# Typescript - setState callback function

Tags: typescript, setstate

I am trying to add types to the argument of a callback function within a setState function that updates its previous value (see below). The argument "previous" has to adhere to the "Previous" type; yet when writing that, I get the following error:

> Argument of type '(previous: Previous) => { oneArg: number;
> anotherArg: number; }[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '[] |
> { oneArg: number; anotherArg: number; }[]'.   Type '(previous:
> Previous) => { oneArg: number; anotherArg: number; }[]' is missing the
> following properties from type '{ oneArg: number; anotherArg: number;
> }[]': pop, push, concat, join, and 28 more.ts(2345)

Anybody could help me out?

```js
type Previous = {
  oneArg: number;
  anotherArg: number;
}[] | [];


type Props = {
setState: (arg: { oneArg: number; anotherArg: number }[] | []) => void;
}
```

```js
function myFunction(someArg: number) {
    props.setState((previous) => {
      return previous.filter((element, index) => {
          return index !== someArg;
        },
      );
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem:
Basically, the type of setState should come from React: `Dispatch<SetStateAction<Previous>>`
where you have to perform the following import (in addition to importing useState):
`import { Dispatch, SetStateAction} from 'react';`

The setState function will then have no problem in taking either an array of objects (in this example) or a callback function as argument.

Also, as Damian was pointing out, `| []` in the Type definition was unnecessary, at it is an implied possibility of `{ oneArg: number; anotherArg: number; }[]`

When hovering now over the argument 'previous' in the expression:
`props.setCart((previous) => {})`
TS infers 'previous' to be of Type 'Previous'.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to specify the type of `previous`. e.g.  `props.setState((previous: Previous) => {`

I'm not sure why you've added `| []`

I also would have expected you to use the type you defined here

```
type Props = {
setState: (arg: Previous) => void;
}
```

For simplicity I would be inclined to make your type:

`type Previous = { oneArg: number; anotherArg: number; }`

and then using it as follows: `setState: (arg: Previous[]) => void;`

Comment: Thanks for your help! If tried exactly that. Now I am thinking that the problem is in the fact the I define Previous to be an array of objects (or an empty array, which could also happen); but setState receives a function as argument below. I have written      setState: (arg: Function) => void;     now,  which eliminates the problem (it seems); however, I've read that the type Function should not be used?

Comment: your code should still work with empty arrays. not sure what you mean about the type `Function`. you've defined the function signature for your function